# Algorithm (especially for c++) to show Every Permutation

Tags: c++, algorithm, recursion, permutation

I need to make a program that use **recursion** with a loop to show **every permutaion**.
let say if input is "abc"
output:

```
a
ab
abc
ac
acb
b
ba
bac
bc
bca
c
cb
cba
ca
cab
```

but i am still able to show (abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba)
Can anyone suggest any **algorithm**. (C++ preferred)

Comment: Share what you got so far, i mean the code, then we can help you.

Comment: "a" is not a permutation of "abc"

Comment: The C++ standard library has `next_permutation`.  Does this do what you want?

Comment: @PaulFloyd. i need to make all possible outputs. `next_permutation` will give `abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba` but how can get others

Comment: @Black_Raven. My code is working to show `abc, acb, bac, bca, cab, cba`

Comment: @Muhammad Faizan those *are* all the *permutations* of "abc". Maybe you don't actually mean permutations?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am watching you since couple of days. Stop being arrogant. Be more emphatic

Comment: @AlBundy 1) How am I arrogant? 2) Why should I be emphatic towards someone who doesn't even attempt at solving the problem, and tries to outsource everything to SO, so that he doesn't have to do anything? If he had, at the very least, attempted to solve the problem, the question would, at the very least, contain their attempt.

Comment: @AlBundy I am sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. It's always about **what** is being commented. Emotions don't translate well via text, so one mustn't even attempt at reading them, since it's very likely, that one would misread them. Your comment is a great example of that.

Comment: Mr. @AlBundy I have desired output in question if you don't understand my question... and by the way it is permutation. according to formula nPr. if r = 1 then you will get single letter permutations. and so on till r = n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want all permutations of each member of the powerset of the input.

```
permSub("abc", "")

func permSub(input, perm)
  print perm
  if input = "" return

  for i = 0 to input.length-1
    permSub(input[0..i]+input[i+1..input.length), perm+input[i]
  end
end
```

Where `input[i..j]` represents the sub string of `input` from `i(inclusive)` to `j(exclusive)`, and `+` is string concatenation.

Note that this will include the empty set, which strictly speaking is correct, but you didn't include it.

Here's the original [Java](https://ideone.com/VZ3Qzf) implementation and my [conversion](https://ideone.com/55Cl1o) to C++, which you should not trust :)

Comment: It's pseudocode. I've added a link to a Java implementation.